# Pyomo and ipopt variables with Integer values from 0 to 5

Tags: python, integer, pyomo, maximize, ipopt

I want to declare two pyomo variables a1 and a2 that can be positive Integer Values from 0 to 5.

I tried to declare the variables as pyo.PositiveIntegers with the "domain" and the "within" parameters.

When I solve the pyomo Problem with 'ipopt' and print out the variables I get the following result:
a1=  2.23
a2=  2.23
which are obviously not integer values.

So how to declare the Variables as Integer and assign the boundaries from 0 to 5 at the same time?

Here is my Code with the simplyfied pyomo Problem:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# Space   x     y    z
space = [2100, 650, 700]

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Variables 1
#model.a1 = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 5), initialize=1)
#model.a2 = pyo.Var(bounds=(0, 5), initialize=1)

model.a1 = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.PositiveIntegers)
model.a2 = pyo.Var(within=pyo.PositiveIntegers)


# variables 2
model.bat1L = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat1B = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat1H = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)

model.bat2L = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat2B = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)
model.bat2H = pyo.Var(bounds=(300, 1200), initialize=301)


# Constraints
model.con1 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1L <= space[0])
model.con2 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1B <= space[1])
model.con3 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1H <= space[2])

model.con4 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2L <= space[0])
model.con5 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2B <= space[1])
model.con6 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat2H <= space[2])

model.con7 = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.bat1L * model.a1 + model.bat2L * model.a2 <= space[0])

# Maximize the Volume inside the avaliable Space

obj_exp = (model.bat1L * model.bat1B * model.bat1H) * model.a1 + (model.bat2L * model.bat2B * model.bat2H) * model.a2

model.obj = pyo.Objective(sense=-1, expr=obj_exp)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = opt.solve(model, tee=False)  # solves and updates model
model.display()

print('a1: ', round(pyo.value(model.a1), 2))
print('L1: ', round(pyo.value(model.bat1L), 0))

print('a2: ', round(pyo.value(model.a2), 2))
print('L2: ', round(pyo.value(model.bat2L), 0))
```

Comment: `ipopt` does not support Mixed Integer NLP's (MINLP).  You'll need to find a different solver if you need to work w/ integers.  Google found this:  https://github.com/coin-or/SHOT which might work

Comment: I was able to solve the Problem by using 'mindtpy' instead of 'ipopt'